# How can I download transaction history of any public address as CSV?

Tags: transaction, taxes

How can I download transaction history of any public address as CSV? Use case: For some 'lost' wallets (lost seed phrase) I need to get the transaction history for Tax Software. Cannot figure out a way to do this using the available blockchain explorers... but this should be relatively easy IMO.

Comment: The data you need is in a fully synced instance of `cardano-db-sync`. All you need is the correct SQL query.

Answer (score 1):

I do not how you could do it as CSV, i guess you must adapt  the data you get from Blockfrost, you can use this endpoint

[https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Addresses/paths/~1addresses~1{address}~1transactions/get](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Addresses/paths/%7E1addresses%7E1%7Baddress%7D%7E1transactions/get)

:) The API usage is pretty straight foward using NodeJs.. but they have support for more languagues like Haskell or Python ... Any how i think there might arise complications from the fact that some wallet uses more than one address for your data analysis tool

Answer (score 0):

This tool does exactly that (based on a set of staking addresses) using the blockfrost.io API, as a CSV or XLSX.

It also can graph the asset balance over time.

https://github.com/pixelsoup42/cardano_account_pandas_dumper